# Merge declaration for type of “hard-coded” class property

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

A library I use has a structure like this:

```
declare module lib.mod {
  export class Obj {
    constructor() {}
    data: {
      foo: any;
      bar: any;
    };
  }
}
```

This is used as so:

```
import * as lib from 'library';

const obj = new lib.mod.Obj();
```

It turns out that the declaration above is incomplete: `data` also has another property (e.g. `baz`). (I realize that things may be left out of public declaration files intentionally, to allow for changing them in updates without breaking code, but in this case I am reasonably certain this is purely a mistake.) What I need to do is to indicate that `obj.data` has this property. I can’t change the file it comes from, and upgrading or replacing this library to something that is typed better is not an immediate option.

Tried a bunch of things that squarely didn’t work, and eventually figured out that I need to format my declaration merge like this:

```
declare module 'library' {
  export module mod {
    export interface Obj {
      data: { baz: any; }
    }
  }
}
```

This causes an error:

> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property '`data`' must be of type '`{ foo: any; bar: any; }`', but here has type '`{ baz: any; }`'. `ts(2717)`

Trying to use `data: { foo: any; bar: any; baz: any; }` doesn’t work either, with the same error except to say that it has that type.

I can write `data2: { baz: any; }`, that will compile without error, and so will `obj.data2.baz`. Problem with that is, it’s wrong—the `Obj` class doesn’t actually have a `data2` property, so this crashes at runtime.

So I can use a declaration merge to add properties to the class, but not—as far as I can tell—to update one of the properties (even if only to add to it). I also can’t update the type of the property itself, because it’s hardcoded—if the original library file had created a `Data` interface and used `data: Data;` in `Obj`, I could just declaration merge to that. But it didn’t.

So, is there any way to update the type of the `data` property here without changing the original library declaration file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't directly do this, the most direct way is to construct a new type based on the Obj type :

```
/// extending Obj but data property
export interface ExtendedObj extends Omit<Obj, "data"> {
    // reusing Obj["data"] definition but add baz property
    data: Obj["data"] & { baz?: any }; //note the question mark .
}
```

the matter is that you have to explicitely "cast" the type each time:

```
const a: ExtendedObj = new Obj();
```

an other way is to use factory to always get the proper type, this method do not require the question mark :

```
/// extending Obj but data property
export interface ExtendedObj extends Omit<Obj, "data"> {
    // reusing Obj["data"] definition but add baz property
    data: Obj["data"] & { baz: any };
}

export const objFactory = (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Obj>) => new 

const b = objFactory();
```

EDIT:

An other solution is to use two helper function that handle casting for you :

```
type BazType: any;

/// extending Obj but data property
export interface ExtendedObj extends Omit<Obj, "data"> {
    // reusing Obj["data"] definition but add baz property
    data: Obj["data"] & { baz?: BazType }; //note the question mark .
}

export function getBaz(o: ExtendedObj) {
    return o.data.baz;
}

export function setBaz(o: ExtendedObj, value: BazType) {
    return o.data.baz = value;
}
```

Again this solution is not perfect and it comes with the cost of more import in your files and two extra functions that could have bad impact in some loops but you can mix this solution with the first one in such cases.

Lastly you could use "property in" guard to check for baz property if you do not need this baz property everywhere in your codebase:

```
const a = new Obj();
if ("baz" in a.data)
    console.log(a.data.baz); //here baz is typed as unknown
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the library returns `Obj` instances pretty often, so that would be a lot of casting.

Comment: depending how large is the library it could be an option to create a proxy module, like with objFactory but for all other functions. An other option that could make the do, create two helper function getBaz(o: ExtendedObj) and setBaz(o:ExtendedObj, value:any) this way, the cast is automaticaly done by TS and your intention is clear.